# Decode and encode in Base45 in Java

Tags: java, encoding, base45

I am following with great interest the digital covid certificate project in java:
https://github.com/ehn-dcc-development/

More specifically, for Java and to decode the pass:
https://github.com/GaetanoPiazzolla/greenpass-decode

Using this code, to decode the base45 string that we read from the QR code, we have:

```
byte[] bytecompressed = Base45.getDecoder().decode(withoutPrefix);
```

I would like to encode this same string back, so I am trying the following:

```
byte[] byteCompressedNew = Base45.getEncoder().encode(bytecompressed);
```

But this results in the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
> Index -23 out of bounds for length 45 at
> nl.minvws.encoding.Base45$Encoder.encode(Base45.java:74)

At this line of code in the base45 module:

```
result[resultIndex++] = toBase45[value % 45];
```

It would be great if you could help me understand what I do wrong.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Where does `Base45` come from? `...` Got it: https://github.com/ehn-dcc-development/base45-java/blob/master/src/main/java/nl/minvws/encoding/Base45.java

Comment: I did not look into the linked code, but a byte value is signed -128 upto 127. And -23 % 45 = -23. It should have been 45-23 = 22. Adding 256 to negative numbers.

Comment: @JoopEggen Looks like there's already a GitHub issue for this? https://github.com/ehn-dcc-development/base45-java/issues/2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to update your dependency from version 0.0.2 to 0.0.3 (released on April 6, 2021 with a bug fix for exactly this problem)

```
io.github.ehn-digital-green-development:base45:0.0.3
```

For maven:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.github.ehn-digital-green-development</groupId>
  <artifactId>base45</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```